# python telegram bot совет

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, текст, работа-с-текстом

Прошу совета сообщества с таким вопросом.
Есть задача написать Телеграмм бота на python.
Он должен выводить заранее заготовленные сообщения из базы\файла при вводе определенных фраз (с этими этапами все понятно)
Вопрос в том каким образом обойти проблему если пользователь напишет слово касса, кассу, кассы, кассой и по разному засклоняем слово или вообще ошибется в написании?
Не хотелось бы смотреть в сторону машинного обучения и тяжелых алгоритмов.
Можно ли обойтись решением попроще?

Заранее благодарю, за любые советы!

Comment: Определить ошибку в буквах можно через алгоритмы расстояния Левенштейна или их аналоги ([пример с библиотекой pyxDamerauLevenshtein](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/44b408140cd3149c67055b835d24063c9743bb86/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/use__pyxdameraulevenshtein/fix_command.py)). А чтобы игнорировать склонения слов используйте нормализация слова, [например через pymorphy2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/44b408140cd3149c67055b835d24063c9743bb86/pymorphy2__examples/normal_form.py)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за совет! pymorphy2 мне подойдет. Если вводить несколько слов то pymorhy cправится? Например "замена кассы"

Comment: Нужно сделать токенизацию, через метод pymorhy и после у каждого слова запросить нормальную форму

Comment: На счёт ошибок в словах: простенькое решение - использовать функционал из [`SequenceMatcher.ratio`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46970fdd8ddc18823519d1e1c57136f6bc2a8dac/Lib/difflib.py#L629) из [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)- и сравнивать насколько строки похожи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал пример токенизации слов, нормализации и исправления опечаток:

- Для токенизации и нормализации используется сторонний модуль `pymorphy2`
- Для исправления опечаток используется встроенные модуль `difflib`
  ** Суть в сравнении двух слов на схожесть и при определенном значении коэффициента (подобрал опытным путем), два слова считаем достаточно похожими
  ** И возвращаем то слово, что наиболее похоже

Пример:

```
from typing import Optional, List
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# pip install pymorphy2
import pymorphy2
from pymorphy2.tokenizers import simple_word_tokenize


morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()


def get_tokens(text: str) -> List[pymorphy2.analyzer.Parse]:
    return [morph.parse(word)[0] for word in simple_word_tokenize(text)]


ALL_WORDS = ['замена', 'заменить', 'касса']


def fix_command(word: str) -> Optional[str]:
    rations = [
        (word2, SequenceMatcher(None, word, word2).ratio())
        for word2 in ALL_WORDS
    ]
    rations = [(word, ratio) for word, ratio in rations if ratio >= 0.7]
    if not rations:
        return 
    
    return max(rations, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]


commands = [
    'замена кассы',
    'заменить кассs',
    'замени кассу',
]
for command in commands:
    words = get_tokens(command)
    norm_words = [fix_command(word.normal_form) for word in words]
    print(command, norm_words)
```

Результат:

```
замена кассы ['замена', 'касса']
заменить кассs ['заменить', 'касса']
замени кассу ['заменить', 'касса']
```